# Add "Edit snippet" to snippets in an answer

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

Sometimes there're several snippets in an answer. It's very confusing/difficult to edit them in that case. Usually you look at a snippet you want to edit. Then you click 'Edit' for the answer it scrolls up to the edit textarea then you should scroll down and search the snippet again and click 'Edit the above snippet`. When you tweak the code, copy-paste small details between snippets it becomes overwhelming. A more advanced solution would be to have all your snippets as tabs or list items in the snippet editor so you can switch between the snippets easily without closing and opening the snippet editor again and again, again and again...

Add here `Edit`:

[image]

Add snippets in an answer as tabs here:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem better or needed at all. I don't have any issue with clicking "edit post" first and then editing snippets via the link already provided. I also don't see how this in any way makes making code changes "overwhelming"; you don't have to save the edit to run the snippet changes.